# Modal NSWindow never released

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, autorelease, nswindowcontroller

[First, please note I'm not using Interface Builder]

I have a NSWindow being shown as a modal sheet when a menu item gets clicked. Here's the code displaying it :

```
let win = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: NSSize(width: 650, height: 400)), styleMask: NSResizableWindowMask, backing: .Nonretained, defer: false)
win.releasedWhenClosed = true
setupController = SetupSheetController(window: win)
mainWindow.beginSheet((setupController!.window)!) { (response: NSModalResponse) in
    print("didClose")
    self.setupController = nil
}
```

`setupController` being defined as an instance variable `var setupController: SetupSheetController?`; and `SetupSheetController` being a `NSWindowController` subclass.

At the time the user is done with this sheet, `self.window?.sheetParent?.endSheet(self.window!, returnCode: NSModalResponseXXX)` gets called by the `setupController`.

My issue being that neither the modal NSWindow nor its controller are getting released. And they're not reused when I reopen the modal sheet, either.
Please also note that I'm not referencing the controller at any other place other than shown here.
Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

OK... Turns out I had to `nil` out the window itself, although using some indirection : `win.windowController?.window = nil` (to be written in the `beginSheet`'s completionHandler).

But it doesn't look very elegant to me. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I think the general idea is that once windows are created they should be reused for the duration of app life. Creating windows is expensive and thus the default behaviour is to create the window lazily the first time it is requested to show and then just hide it once it is finished. Of course that also requires you to keep a persistent reference to the controller.